# java giving .9999999 instead of a rounded whole number

Tags: java, double, divide

Here is the extracted code :

```
long timeMs = 1473;
double timeS = (timeMs / 1000) + (timeMs% 1000) / 1000.0;
System.out.println(timeS);
```

And the output is:

```
1.4729999999999999
```

So basically, I was just trying to convert the time taken in seconds into milliseconds.
After I saw this I thought my method is wrong, so I've tried other inputs, such as 1472, 1474, 1173, 3 etc which all gave the correct values(1.472, 1.474, 1.173, 0.003).

I think I've came across something similar to this a while ago in a book called Java Puzzlers, but have forgotten. Can anyone tell me why this is happening (and a proper term/error)?

Thanks.

Comment: Floating point precision.

Comment: -1 floating point .. Google it.

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You get the correct result from the correct division.  Just use `timeMs / 1000.0`.  With it I get `1.473`.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I do not understand why I need to be down voted, is it because its a simple question? It may be in your eyes... but how can I possibly know otherwise? why do people like you expect a beginner to know these technical terms and search for it? If I knew what to search, it would have taken much much less time than asking here.

Comment: @Topstar it was asked million times before on SO and you get a nice autocomplete when you ask a question. That's why.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea Autocomplete? Did I ask for a code? I only asked the reasons for it happening, and the proper term. As I've said, I couldn't find the proper terms for the error. Next time I hope you read the question. Don't assume everyone has intentions like yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead, but it's because of [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) rounding rules.

```
double timeS = (timeMs / 1000.0); //+ ((double) (timeMs % 1000) / 1000.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BigDecimal for more accurate rounding and scaling.

```
   long timeMs = 1473;
   double timeS = (timeMs / 1000d);
   BigDecimal usefulName = new BigDecimal(timeS).setScale(3, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
   System.out.println(usefulName);
```